# Skip price rules for API-created orders

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento-2.2.5, price-rules

Our price rules are used for discounts. Some of our orders come in via the API. Our API orders must not have any discount applied. How can I achieve this?

At the moment, price rules are applied to orders created via the API the same way as to orders created via the shop frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by setting applied_rule_ids field as null in quote table. You need to create a preference of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote.php and create function as

```
public function setAppliedRuleIds(null)
{
    $this->setData('applied_rule_ids', null);
    return $this;
}
```

Make sure you defined preference in webapi_rest folder's di.xml so that it will work for rest api only.

Its only suggestion so I am not sure it will work for you as I haven't tried this. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you @ramkishan. I tried, but it did not work. In `src/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php`, firstly the `rulesApplier->applyRules` is used, before the `setAppliedRuleIds` method sets the ids. Commenting out the `setAppliedRuleIds` did not have any impact.

I was more successful returning an empty array from the function `_getRules` in the same file; I think I could write a plugin for that. Now just not sure about how to access order-level properties / attributes from that plugin...